# Boxplot and groupby: Issue with groups and sharex

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

Here is my datasets:

```
df
    A    B      C
0  13  Yes  False
1  12   No   True
2   2  Yes   True
3  12   No  False
4   4   No   True
5   1  Yes   True
6   1   No  False
7   5   No   True
8  15  Yes  False
```

and

```
df2
    A    B      C
0  13  Yes  False
1  12   No  False
2  11   No  False
3  15  Yes  False
4  12   No  False
5  21  Yes  False
```

Here is the piece of problematic code:

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots(2,1, sharey="all", sharex="all")
df2.boxplot("A", by=["B","C"], ax=ax[0])
df.boxplot("A", by=["B","C"], ax=ax[1])
```

which gives
[image: boxplot]

**The problem** I have, is that, in the upper subplot, the boxplot on the right hand side should be shifted of 1 to right to align with the `(Yes, False)` label.

I think it comes from the fact that `sharex` doesn't care much about the xticklabels, but rather the xticks values (which are `[1,2]` and `[1,2,3,4]`). I can fix this with the `positions=[1,3]` argument in `df2.boxplot`.

The question is, how can I fix this without that prior knowledge of which groups won't be represented ?

Also, could this be a Pandas or Matplotlib bug, or this behavior is expected for certain reason ?

Comment: Did you try the answers from here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25284859/grouping-boxplots-in-seaborn-when-input-is-a-dataframe ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
import seaborn as sns
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame([[13, 'Yes', False],
       [12, 'No', True],
       [2, 'Yes', True],
       [12, 'No', False],
       [4, 'No', True],
       [1, 'Yes', True],
       [1, 'No', False],
       [5, 'No', True],
       [15, 'Yes', False]],
       columns = list('ABC'))
df2 = pd.DataFrame([[13, 'Yes', False],
       [12, 'No', False],
       [11, 'No', False],
       [15, 'Yes', False],
       [12, 'No', False],
       [21, 'Yes', False]],
       columns = list('ABC'))
df['i'] = 1
df2['i'] = 2
dfb = pd.concat([df,df2])
dfb['B,C'] = map(lambda x,y: '%s, %s'%(str(x),str(y)), dfb.B, dfb.C)
dfb2 = pd.DataFrame(dfb, columns=['A','i','B,C'])
sns.factorplot('B,C', row='i',y='A', kind='box', data=dfb2)
```

[image]

Added an identifier `i` to each dataframe to distinguish them once concatenated, combined existing variables `B, C` so I could pass them as the x-argument to factorplot.  That was trying to reproduce your figure. Letting factorplot do a bit more of it:

```
dfc = pd.concat([df,df2])
sns.factorplot('B', row='i', col='C', y='A', kind='box', data=dfc)
```

[image]

That certainly makes clear which case doesn't have any data!